# Failing gnome-shell theme: where can I find errors/configuration apart from gnome-tweak-tool?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes

I have a gnome-shell desktop that, since the update from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, acts strange. In detail, I have a high CPU activity that seems (looking from other questions here) could be triggered by a theme error. 
Now, I have no special theme installed --- but the gnome-tweak-tool is reporting an error (look at the screenshot down here). Given that:

- the theme list is "locked"
- the warning signal is not clickable
- running gnome-tweak-tool in a terminal shows no useful errors
- activating lookingGlass shows no error whatsoever
- .xsession-errors has not errors

Anyone knows where can I see for the specific error, or how to reset the configuration without deleting all the .dconf directory? 
[image: screenshot of the "advanced settings" menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL, that's not really an error. It just means you don't have any themes installed. It'll go away if you install some themes. Don't worry about it. :)

However, I am concerned about the high CPU activity. Have you looked at System Monitor to see what is taking up so much CPU?

Comment: Yes --- the process "gnome-shell" is using an average 35% CPU. That happens on my desktop box (radeon 2400) and not on my laptop (Intel graphics).

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled? If so, try disabling them one by one and check the System Monitor each time you disable one. One of them may be causing the issue. Do the same with any programs you have starting up with Gnome Shell.

Comment: Triec to even un-install all the extension, nothing helps. I do not understand what you mean with "starting with gnome-shell". I start gkrellm and a log watcher, but they are different processes. The process which use 35% cpu is just "gnome-shell"...

Comment: What CPU are you using?

Comment: Intel Core2 VPro. Why? I can see why it could be related to the graphic driver, less with the CPU... in my netbook, much less powerful than the desktop machine, gnome-shell uses just 1-2%.

Comment: I was just asking because if it was an older CPU I would see why it's taking up 35% of the CPU.

Comment: What video card are you working with? Are you using the ATI/Nvidia drivers or the video drivers that come with Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear: I am using an ATI card (see my first comment) with the ATI catalist drivers shipped by ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried running it without the ATI driver? It may be a driver issue...

Answer (score 1):

Found it --- it is the proprietary ATI drivers. Using the system settings, additional drivers, disabling the ATI drivers fixed CPU usage of gnome shell back where it was.

The system seems a bit slower in booting the graphic interface, but afterwards it works quite well --- note however that I do not use 3d graphics. The graphic card is an ATI Radeon HD2400 Pro.